# How do I block requests with URLS that start with certain characters in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that you have to put code in background.js for it to work, obviously. For example, if I wanted to block all requests starting with "facebook.com/s/", how would I do this? I've been looking everywhere on how to do this but to no avail. Code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details);
    
    if(details.url.startsWith("https://www.facebook.com/s/"))
    {
        return{cancel:true};
    }

},{urls: ['<all_urls>']},['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);
```

Comment: Use declarativeNetRequest: [info and examples](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/). You won't even need a background script!

Comment: @wOxxOm How would I form the JSON to make it block all URLs starting with "facebook.com/s/" for example? Like this?

"urlFilter": "s/",
"domains": [ "www.facebook.com" ],

Comment: "urlFilter": "||facebook.com/s/" and you don't need `domains` unless you want to ignore these requests on non-facebook sites.